# Converting JSON files to Parquet format through avro format

Tags: java, json, bigdata, avro, parquet

I have a huge number of JSON files, all the JSON files contain a subset of ~200 attributes, most of which are complex attributes (the attribute has multiple nested attributes). Not all the attributes are necessarily present in all the JSON files.

I want to convert these JSONs to Parquet formatted file, searching for a way to do this, I found out that I need to convert the JSONs to avro format, then convert the avro formatted data to Parquet format.

My problem is that I can't find a way to extract the avro schema, trying to use `JsonUtil.inferSchema` will not work since not all the attributes are present in every json file. I have the attributes present in POJO java class in a library, but using avro reflection to get the schema does not work because the pojo has generics in it, which is still not supported in avro. My last resort will be to write the schema manually but it is going to be very time consuming.

Is there any other way to get the avro schema? This is a problem that I have been trying to find a solution to for the past two days and is frustrating me.

Comment: Hey did you happen to find a solution to this? @user2001241